# Do we have a one to one correspondence between positive roots and reflections in a Coxeter group?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, abstract-algebra

By the answer of [the question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255919/references-request-reflections-in-coxeter-groups), the set of reflections of a Coxeter system $(W,S)$ is given by $R = \{ wsw^{-1} : w \in W, s \in S\}$.

Do we have a one to one correspondence between positive roots and reflections in a Coxeter group?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, as long as the root system is reduced.  See Proposition 1.14 of Humphrey's "Reflection groups and Coxeter groups".

Comment: This "yes" only applies to finite Coxeter groups, I believe.

Comment: @ChristianStump, yes, you are right, although [your answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/256115/2383) shows that it's true in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest, you really look carefully into the reference "Humphreys, Reflection and Coxeter groups" ([link behind paywall](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1066460)), as you again find the answer there.
Please look into the reference for details below. In case, you have no access to it, you might be lucky searching for it on the web (you can also drop me a line).

First, one has to define a root system for $W$ (done in Section 5.4) as $\Phi = \{w(\alpha_s) : w \in W, s \in S\}$. Then there is a decomposition $\Phi = \Phi^+ \sqcup -\Phi^+$ with $\Phi^+ = \Phi \cap \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\Delta$ for $\Delta = \{\alpha_s : s \in S\}$.
And finally, by construction, $R = \{ s_\beta : \beta \in \Phi^+\}$ and this is a bijective correspondence. So the answer to your question is **yes**.

Comment: Note that the definition of "reflection" here is pretty far from any specific kind of geometry, but within the abstract theory of Coxeter groups it works surprisingly well as a generalization of the usual notion for finite real reflection groups acting on a euclidean space.